# CUDA Time Events

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu

I am timing how long it takes my CUDA program to calculate matrices of a certain size.  For example, 10x10, 100x100, 500x500,100x1000.

However, the results are not at all what I was expecting.  The numbers for the graph are not at what is expected.  With the increase in size of the matrices, the computational time decreases.

For example, here is the average time (from 1000 runs):
10x10: 0.032768s
100x100: 0.068960s
500x500: 0.006336s
1000x1000: 0.018400s

The time goes down, then up again at 1000.  What is going on?  Shouldn't the numbers peak off at a certain point?  Why is it going in a roller coaster like this?

Here is how the actual timing code is being run:

```
int blocksNeeded=0;
cudaError_t cudaStatus;
blocksNeeded=(size/MAXTHREADS)+1;
int threadsPerBlock = MAXTHREADS/blocksNeeded+1;
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
float elapsedtime;
.
.
.
.
.
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop); 
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
addKernel<<<blocksNeeded, size>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b,size);
cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0); 
cudaEventSynchronize(stop); 
cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedtime, start, stop);
cudaEventDestroy(start);
cudaEventDestroy(stop);
```

where MAXTHREADS are 1024 and, size is the amount of elements I have in the matrix. I.E. 10x10 matrix will have 100 elements which is the size.

Updated with kernel:

```
__global__ void addKernel(float *c, float *a, float *b,int size)
{
    int idx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(idx < size) 
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];

}
```

Comment: Are you checking the return codes from the kernel execution? Maybe at 500, the kernel failed to launch

Comment: How are you calculating blocksNeeded and size ?

Comment: Have you tried without the cudaDeviceSynchronize? It is not needed for the timing and it might affect the results (even if not in the way you described). And +1 to the other comments.

Comment: @flipchar The kernels are launching fine because I check the results file that the sums are written too and it is all there.

Comment: @jmsu I just tried that and for a 1000x1000, it's flucating between .01 and .08 every 5 runs or so.

Comment: @Pavan, I just updated the blocksNeeded and size.

Comment: can you post the kernel? maybe your out of bounds, calculating something wrong and get floating point exceptions on your gpu. this can cause kernels to execute much longer than they should. also: what gpu are you using?

Comment: @kronos Updated for you. I have a GTX560Ti

Comment: Also is the units in seconds?

Comment: It is milliseconds, it is stated in the CUDA Toolkit reference manual.

Comment: Sorry I did read that but was thinking in secs. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a test on a recent GPU cluster equipped with NVIDIA Tesla M2090. Basically i'm performing a vector addition with different sizes. The results are:

```
Size     Kernel time (msec)
===========================
2        0.04
4        0.010912
8        0.012128
16       0.012256
32       0.011296
64       0.01248
128      0.012192
256      0.012576
512      0.012416
1024     0.012736
2048     0.01232
4096     0.011968
8192     0.011264
16384    0.007296
32768    0.007776
65536    0.009728
131072   0.018304
262144   0.031392
524288   0.055168
1048576  0.10352
```

What you can see is, that there is knee at a vector size of 16384, which basically resembles your observations. This is **not** an error but normal behavior since the GPU has to be utilized for showing performance. The point of utilization is, in case of the Tesla M2090, reached around 16384 parallel additions.

The way you are measuring kernel performance is perfectly ok. I assume you've taken this from the "Best Practices Guide" for CUDA.

**Notice:** Please consider that the shown data is generated by using a *single* kernel run, i. e. it is not representative. Generally for exact time measurements the kernel should run multiple times with the same problem and the kernel time is the mean of the runs.

Comment: +1 for providing data but... measurement is great but still does not explain why it happens. Why is the size 2 bigger than 4? Excluding the 2, for all other valid values the times peak at size 1024, expected. At 2048, the first bad kernel parameter the times start decreasing but why aren't they constant? Doesn't the kernel just fail?

Comment: Thanks for providing the data, I appreciate it. I'm running into problems where if I run more than 2000 it seg faults, but I am currently trying to fix that. When you say 16384 parallel additions, is that the max amount of threads the Tesla has?

Comment: @jmsu: The times for sizes 2 to 8192 are roughly equal. The decreasing at 16384 is not due an kernel error but to different utilization of the device. A GPU is a massively parallel device where a certain impact is only seen with larger problems. Furthermore it depends on the relation between number of blocks and blocksize. For this example blocksize = 256. Making the blocksize larger would result in different results.

Comment: @Dan: No. This just shows that the device is able to schedule the task differently, gaining a greater speedup. 16384 threads is not the maximum, this depends on the combination of number of blocks and threads per block. Check the NVIDIA CUDA manuals for device capabilities.

Comment: But are you using his code with threads per block = size or you fixed that at 256? Because what I said was assuming the threads per block = size which shouldn't be able to produce any results with size > 1536.

Comment: @jmsu: I see, no this is my own implementation with threads-per-block fixed to 256. I assume that changing this value results in a different curve. Sorry for not mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the kernel with

```
addKernel<<<blocksNeeded, MAXTHREADS>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b,size);
```

The second parameter on a kernel call is the number of threads to launch in each block, not the total number of threads.

At 100x100 you are already exceeding the maximum number of threads per block which is 1536 for compute capability 2.x

And just noticed that you calculate some kind of threadsPerBlock which is wrong and that you don't use it. Choose a number of threads per block. Then divide by the total number of elements to process and add 1 to it if the remainder is different from 0 and you get the number of blocks to launch.

Comment: But this does not explains why his measures are lower for 500x500 and 1000x1000. Or am i missing something?

Comment: It explains because kernel fails to launch, invalid parameters error or something like that. I am not seeing why they aren't lower for 100x100 also but with errors you can't expect reliable results.

Comment: I agree, but he states that all kernels are executed without errors

Comment: Good point... I can't explain that! Magic! But he still must do actual error checking instead of just saying the files are there with values.

Comment: I'll give it a try on our GPU cluster...but i think this is regular behavior, since the GPU has to be utilized a bit, which happens beginning with 500x500, but this is just a guess.